# SharePoint - How to: Duplicate the same web part containing multiple quick links to multiple pages on the same site

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, sitepages, quick-links

Good Day All,

Been Googling for hours and nothing seems similar.

In SharePoint, I'd like to copy a 'web part' which contains multiple 'Quick links' to multiple pages on the same site. The pages are already created, so I don't want to copy the entire first page into new pages.

I see the functionality to duplicate web parts on the same page, but how does one duplicate a web part (of multiple quick links) to multiple pages?

Thoughts and feedback would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible in SharePoint online using user interface (UI).

You cannot copy web part & it's configuration from one page to another page from SharePoint UI.

---

Not sure if it helps you, but there are few cmdlets in PnP PowerShell related to web parts, check below links:

1. [Get-PnPWebPartXml](https://pnp.github.io/powershell/cmdlets/Get-PnPWebPartXml.html)
2. [Get-PnPWebPart](https://pnp.github.io/powershell/cmdlets/Get-PnPWebPart.html)
3. [Add-PnPWebPartToWebPartPage](https://pnp.github.io/powershell/cmdlets/Add-PnPWebPartToWebPartPage.html)

Answer (score 1):

Up on the top bar click the plus + next to "New" then select "copy this page" allows you to make a complete copy, change the web link names and all the other links to it.